# Error creating dataSource bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

The `dataSource` is defined in this class and I am using the same bean in `springSecurityConfig.java` class but it is giving me error : 
`No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available`

ShoppingServletConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.shopping")
public class ShoppingServletConfig {
 @Primary
 @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopping");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

   }
```

SpringSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource")
DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
    .jdbcAuthentication()
    .dataSource(dataSource)
    .usersByUsernameQuery(
               "select username,password, enabled from user where user_name=?")
              .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
               "select username, role from user_roles where user_name=?");
}
```

error in console is like this :

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityConfig':
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=dataSource)}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
 Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=dataSource)}
```

Comment: Check whether `SpringSecurityConfig` is coming under the package `com.project.shopping` or a sub package of it.

Comment: @shazin it is under com.project.shopping.configuration package  'ShoppingServletConfig' is also on the same package

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do it like this where I force Spring to do the dependency management on an explicit bean. 
The configuration interface is returned as an anonymous class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

@Bean
public WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter securityAdapter (DataSource dataSource) {
    return new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter () {
        @Override
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from user where user_name=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where user_name=?");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: it gave the same problem

Comment: adding '@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.shopping")' to  SpringSecurityConfig.java solved the problem. 

Do we need to add the @ComponentScan(basePackage="#") to communicate the bean between the class annotated with @Configuration ?

Comment: Yes, if you're not using `Spring Boot` which automatically autoscan's, then you'll need to explicitly load the above configuration with either `@Import({SpringSecurityConfig.class})` or a base class config scan (like you did) with `@ComponentScan`